# Move output of Find command unix

Tags: shell, unix, ubuntu

Im learning unix programming , i want to find all files whose size is greater than 1M an print them into a file.

here is my code

```
find. -size +1M -print0 | xargs -I -O '{}' mv '{}' files
```

all sites i have found refer to this one as right one , but it does not work . currently im working on ubuntu

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: Your question asks print them into a file., the code tries to move. Do you really want to move them or do you only want a file with a list of all large files?

Answer (score 3):

You mis-copied/mis-typed the commend from wherever you found it.

1. The first `{}` is the argument to `-I`.
2. `-O` is not an argument to `xargs` you meant `-0` (to go with `-print0`).
3. You missed the space between `find` and `.` (the current directory).

Which would get you:

```
find . -size +1M -print0 | xargs -0 -I '{}' mv '{}' files
```

That being said you don't need `xargs` here at all since `find` can execute commands directly.

```
find . -size +1M -exec mv {} files \+
```

And it is generally a good idea to test a complicated `find` command before you run it.

Using `find . -size +1M` by itself will just print the matching files.

Using

```
find . -size +1M -ok mv {} files \+
```

will cause `find` to prompt you before each execution of the command.

Comment: i miss copied it here , sorry , but as before , it does literally nothing , no error , just another $ expecting  or letting me know i can write , it doe not create or update file with those informations

Comment: Does `find . -size +1M` output anything? If not then it isn't finding any files that match.

Comment: Do you get prompted when you use the `-ok` version?

Comment: im new to unix and i fail to find -ok version of find. could you elaborate?

Comment: I meant the `find . -size +1M -ok mv {} files \+` command from my answer. Your `find` might not have `-exec +` so you might need to use `find . -size +1M -ok mv {} files \;` or it might not support `-ok` at all I guess. But I would expect most (if not all) versions of Ubuntu to support both of those.